# Testcase in allure report showing as passed tests even when there are failures for some testdata

Tags: java, selenium, testng, allure

I ran a testcase with multiple test data and one got failed and remaining got passed but the allure report at suites level is showing as passed for the Testcase. When I go to retries tab failed testcaes is available with failed status.

I want to make the overall status of that testcase as failed in allure report suites level even if a single test data fails in retries tab. Can someone help me with your suggestions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can only speculate based on my own experience, that this might occur in situations where there are multiple directories where test results may be stored. For example, let's consider a scenario where we are using TestNG, the `maven-surefire-plugin`, and the Allure framework. The results are stored by default in both `target/allure-results` and in `target/surefire-reports`.

When you run `allure serve target/surefire-reports/`, it behaves as described because Allure takes not its own results from there and does the best it can with them. It displays them but it is far from this what we expect.

When you run `allure serve target/allure-results/`, it behaves as it should, with each test treated separately and not counted as a retry.

Of course, this is just my speculation. In general, it's a good idea to check the `target` directory (or the `build` directory if using Gradle) and thoroughly examine what and where is being collected.

In order to provide better answer, it is necessary to know which plugins you are using, what their configuration is, and how the Allure reports are generated.